# Ubuntu bootable dvd

Tags: boot

I'm looking for a list of the files and directories that should be on a bootable DVD created from the Ubuntu iso file named Ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64. I've created the DVD but it will not boot from my Acer Travelmate 4061. All bios boot requirements have been fulfilled (inoperable XP on the hard drive but drive still accessable)

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.list?

Comment: @muru OP is running a Pentium M, which is 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is probably only capable to run 32-bit software see [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/27590/Intel-Pentium-M-Processor-740-2M-Cache-1_73-GHz-533-MHz-FSB). So you will have to get a 32-bit image form here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

To verify that the download worked correctly check this how-to: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify

Comment: Thank You to Muru and Patrick for the information.  I've since downloaded the 32 bit version, burned a DVD, verified the write and had the same results regarding booting from the DVD.  It seems to spend an inordinate amount of time accessing the DVD but then stops and tries to boot from the internal hard drive (and fails of course as the XP OS seems to have a corrupt file).  Any further ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: does this dvd boot on an other machine?

Comment: As above, if available test it on other machine. Meanwhile, how exactly have you burned the ISO?

Comment: Yes, it does boot from DVD to an HP Envy dv7 (AMD turion(tm) II and the complete OS operates.  I suppose this points to a malfunctioning DVD player on the other laptop.